# "Cannot implicitly covert type float? to float"

Tags: c#, floating-point

I'm trying to subtract 2 variables(`float xdiff = x1 - x2;`) of float format however I'm getting the error "Cannot implicitly covert type float? to float". Values `d,c,s,m,radius,x1,y1,x2,y2` are obtained from windows forms input.

Code is as follows;

```
    public Nullable<float> d = null;

    public Nullable<float> c = null;

    public Nullable<float> s = null;

    public Nullable<float> m = null;

    public Nullable<float> radius = null;

    public Nullable<float> x1 = null;

    public Nullable<float> y1 = null;

    public Nullable<float> x2 = null;

    public Nullable<float> y2 = null;



private void Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            d = float.Parse(this.downwind.Text);
            c = float.Parse(this.crosswind.Text);
            s = float.Parse(this.maxcross.Text);
            m = float.Parse(this.offset.Text);
            radius = float.Parse(this.rad.Text);
            x1 = float.Parse(this.x1coord.Text);
            y1 = float.Parse(this.y1coord.Text);
            x2 = float.Parse(this.x2coord.Text);
            y2 = float.Parse(this.y2coord.Text);

            float xdiff = x1 - x2;


        }
```

Comment: don't use ``float.Parse``because will throw an exception is the ``Text`` not convertible to ``float``, use instead ``float.TryParse``

Comment: @Sajid Thank you. I will implement that

Comment: You should use `float? xdiff = x1 - x2;`

Comment: @MKR, the result gives you ``null`` if ``x1:null`` and ``x2:1`` for example

Comment: @Sajid Agree. I meant using `float.TryParse` is best way. But if OP desires to have `null` value then he can use the way I have mentioned. I prefer to use `var xdiff =  x1 - x2` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you take care of all NULL Scenarios, below should solve it.

```
float xdiff = (x1 - x2).Value;
```

Comment: Thank you. It did solve it. Could you explain to me why this works? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Well the difference between float and float? (or Nullable<float>) is that the later allows you to hold null values while float doesnt have a null value. To Gracefully (in CLR's opionion) handle this, Nullable<T> is a wrapper which provides properties like .HasValue and .Value. Read about it on MSDN.

Comment: Be aware this will only work if `x1` and `x2` are not null. If they are not null there is no reason to use `float?` at all.

Comment: @DourHighArch You are correct. OP has declared both `x1` and `x2` as `Nullable` float. Hence, this will not work until declaration is corrected.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Though I have not down-voted but this solution will not work until declaration is corrected. It will be good if you cover that point and declare `x1` and `x2` as float otherwise future user will be confused. You have provided good reference in comment.

Comment: @DourHighArch - Thats why I said in the opening line - Assuming OP takes care of Null scenarios

Comment: @MKR - What do you mean by fixing the declaration. Other than Null scenarios - the solution works. As I said on the first line - Assuming OP takes care of NUL: Scenarios before this line of code.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Mentioning `Assuming OP takes care of Null scenarios` is not very specific. You can mention to change declaration of those variables (or declare it again). Such things does not impress people here and someone would have downvoted. Second part is : Why `.Value` is needed?

Comment: Well SO is always divided. At times when I have suggested alternatives, fellow responders say Stick to the current code and provide solution to his implementation. Do not suggest alternate ways. Now here I have you saying no teach the OP a better approach.

Comment: .Value is needed coz x1 and x2 are Nullable<T> the difference will be Nullable<T> too. Since OP wants to receive the value in a Float type.

Comment: `if (x1.HasValue == true && x2.HasValue == true && y1.HasValue == true && y2.HasValue == true && m.HasValue == true)` I've used this to ensure that Null scenarios are taken care of. @MKR your solution also works.

Answer (score 1):

If `x1` and `x2` are expected to be of type `float?` then result of operation `x1 - x2` can be `null` (if ether value is `null`). Hence, the result is expected to be stored in `float?`.   [Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

You should use

```
float? xdiff = x1 - x2;
```

Or best could be:

```
var xdiff = x1 - x2;  //Using var will automatically decide type of result
```

Comment: Remember using `float?` is valid but then result should be stored in of matching type. because say `40.0 - null = null`